# DNN share module content from different templates

Tags: templates, dotnetnuke

I installed a DNN skin which comes with several templates. Now these templates share the same footer for example: contact us, gallery, about us etc. . .

Is there a way where I can make these modules all share the same content using different templates? I am importing about 7 templates in the website but when I can the content of one of the footers the others content is not changed. Any Ideas on how I can link these together so in the future when I need to change something all of them follows?

Answer (score 0):

You can share content across pages in DNN using the "Display On All Pages" setting in the module settings.

1) Install a module into the Footer on ONE page.
2) Configure the Module Settings for that module to "Display On All Pages"
3) Done

Any changes made to the module, should reflect across all pages. It won't matter which page you make the change on either.

Note: Modules that are set to display on all pages will attempt to load in a PANE of the same name, so if your "layouts" all have a FooterPane, the module will appear there. If you have any layouts that don't have a FooterPane, the module will appear in the ContentPane of that page.

Deleting a module from one page is possible through the module Actions.

To remove the module from all pages, you have to go to the Module Settings, and unselect the Display On All Pages option. The module will then remain on THAT page, but not on any other pages.

All the "deleted" modules (after unselecting Display On All Pages) will be in the Admin/Recycle Bin